# Roxygen2 adds `import(RcppArmadillo)` to my `NAMESPACE`

Tags: r, roxygen2, rcpparmadillo

Can I stop it?
That requires to add RcppArmadillo to Imports, when otherwise LinkingTo would be enough.

Does this already trigger Roxygen to do this?

```
#include "RcppArmadillo.h"
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
```